# Bison default precedence resolution

Tags: parsing, bison

I'm writing a Bison inspired parsing framework, and there's something in the Bison manual that I don't really understand.

From the Bison manual 5.3.5 How Precedence Works:

> ...each rule gets its precedence from the last terminal symbol mentioned in the components.

and

> Not all rules and not all tokens have precedence. If either the rule or the lookahead token has no precedence, then the default is to shift.

As far as I can understand, this comes down to:

- Token has precedence, rule doesn't -> shift
- Rule has precedence, token doesn't -> shift
- Neither has any precedence -> shift
- Both have precedence:

  - Token has higher precedence -> shift
  - Rule has higher precedence -> reduce
  - Equal precedence -> use the associativity of the precedence level to determine action

But wouldn't that mean that a rule that doesn't contain any terminal symbol with a declared precedence would never be reduced? What am I missing?

For example, the below grammar:

`S -> E + E
E -> foo1
E -> foo2`

Gives a dfa with seven states, the first two are:

- State 0

  - Items:

    - S' -> . S $
    - S  -> . E + E
    - E  -> . foo1
    - E  -> . foo2
  - Edges:

    - E -> 3
    - S -> 4
    - foo1 -> 1
    - foo2 -> 2
- State 1

  - Items:

    - E -> foo1 . lookahead: +,$

When parsing the string foo1 + foo2, the parser shifts the token foo1 and ends up in state 1. The next lookahead token is +, neither '+' nor the rule E -> foo1 has any declared precedence, which means the parser should shift, but there is no such edge in state 1, which leads the parser to return a syntax error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precedence rules only apply in the case of ambiguity; that is to say, if there is a shift/reduce conflict. Absent any conflict, the parser will shift or reduce based on the grammar.

Comment: Yeah, after reading my own question a couple of times I gathered that that must be the case :) makes sense